# Rename child in MongoDb PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to rename a child in mongodb from the PHP Library (https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/tutorial/)

My document structure is

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a57c33f2ae9aa144244fa84"),
"personalizados" : {
    "Moto" : "Ducati",
    "Auto1" : "Fitito"
},
"id_mysql" : 8,
"nombre" : "Julián Gó"
}
```

And I want to rename "Moto" or "Auto1" (childs of personalizados)

I'm trying with:

```
$mongo_clientes->updateMany(
    [], 
    ['$rename' => 
        [array('personalizados.' . $campo_actual['etiqueta']) => array('personalizados.' . $etiqueta)]
    ]
);
```

Where $campo_actual['etiqueta'] is the old name and $etiqueta is the new, but it does not work... Do you know what is wrong?

EDIT: I getting this error:

```
Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: document to insert contains invalid key: empty key
```

pd: $mongo_clientes is the collection and is working fine, it works with another things like inserts

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is:

```
$mongo_clientes->updateMany([], ['$rename' => ['personalizados.' . $campo_actual['etiqueta'] => 'personalizados.' . $etiqueta]]);
```